# How to get a class with a unknown name with require()

Tags: javascript, class

I have a template class file called

`./templates/Class.js`

```js
class Template {
//code
}
```

Then I have another class called:

`./classes/Foo.js`

```js
const Template = require('./../../templates/Class.js')
class Foo extends Template {
//code
}
```

I have a main file called: `./index.js`, which checks all files under `./classes/`, and checks if it's a

```js
classname instanceof Template;
```

So I can't keep track of all the classnames under `./classes/`, and I want to require all files under `./classes/`, check for any classes for each file that extends off of my `Template` class, and add that class/function to a map. I know how to require all files under `./classes/` but not much after that, so how do I do that?

HOW I REQUIRE FILES:
`index.js`

```js
const getAllFiles = function(dirPath, arrayOfFiles) {
  files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)

  arrayOfFiles = arrayOfFiles || []

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    if (fs.statSync(dirPath + "/" + file).isDirectory()) {
      arrayOfFiles = getAllFiles(dirPath + "/" + file, arrayOfFiles)
    } else {
      if(fs.readdirSync(dirPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js') && fs.statSync(dirPath + "/" + file).isFile()).length) {
      arrayOfFiles.push(dirPath + "/" + file)
      }
    }
  })

  return arrayOfFiles;
};
```

Comment: How do you currently require all files in the folder?

Comment: updated question